# Officejs add/activate a new worksheet throw a GeneralException

Tags: excel, office-js

We are building an Excel add-in by using a dialog. The dialog box will delivery a message to its parent/opener workbook. The function file will call a simple function as example:

```
const populateTable = (officeMessage)=>{
      Excel.run(async context => {
        const workbook = context.workbook;
        const worksheets = workbook.worksheets;
        const sheet = worksheets.add();

        sheet.getCell(0,0).values = [[officeMessage]];

        await context.sync();

      }).then(()=>{
        showDialogEvent.completed();
        dialog.close();
      }).catch(handleError);
    }
```

Two workbook/excel desktop have been opened (**Excel1 and Excel2**). The dialog is opened in **Excel1**. However, if I focus another workbook(**Excel2**) before this function is triggered. Officejs API will create a new worksheet in **Excel2** instead **Excel1**, and an error will be thrown as below:

`{"description":"There was an internal error while processing the request.","name":"RichApi.Error","code":"GeneralException","traceMessages":[],"innerError":null,"debugInfo":{"code":"GeneralException","message":"There was an internal error while processing the request.","errorLocation":"WorksheetCollection.add","statement":"var add=worksheets.add();","surroundingStatements":["var workbook=context.workbook;","var worksheets=workbook.worksheets;","// >>>>>","var add=worksheets.add();","// <<<<<","var cell=add.getCell(...);","// Instantiate {cell}","cell.values=...;"],"fullStatements":["Please enable config.extendedErrorLogging to see full statements."]},"stack":"GeneralException: There was an internal error while processing the request.\n   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:24:286584)\n   at Anonymous function (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js:1:822)"}`

***Note:*** I tried to save the first workbook's **Request Context** in memory and pass it into **Excel.run**, but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ericl for your report.
This is a known issue, we are working on a new feature (3743479) to fix this issue, A [uservoice request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/39781582-fix-generalexceptions-being-thrown-when-multiple-e) was created , you could also upvote this request. 
Please listen to this user voice, we will keep posted once we release this feature

The [workaround](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/force-excel-to-open-new-instance) currently is to force to open another instance/process of Excel to solve this problem.